# Alloy - Irreflexivity

Tags: alloy

I just started using Alloy. I have a question about the following minimal example:

```
module test

abstract sig MySig {    
  my_rel : set MySig
}

//fact my_rel_irrefl {no iden & my_rel }   // this works
fact my_rel_irrelfl {my_rel not in iden} // this does not work

run {}
```

Why is the second my_rel_irrelfl not working? My thinking was that, e.g.

MySig = {N0,N1,N2}
iden = {(N0,N0),(N1,N1),(N2,N2)}

If there is an element (x,x), where x in MySig in the relation my_rel then it has to be in iden as well.

However, I get this model:

[model found by alloy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G9Dl.png)

I.e. one where my_rel is reflexive.

Comment: Tip: instead of making this both facts, make them predicates, and do `check {pred1 <=> pred2}`. That will give you a counterexample where one is true and the other is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`my_rel not in iden` says that `my_rel` is not a *subset* of `iden`. Since `N0 -> N1 in my_rel` and `N0 -> N1 not in iden`, `my_rel` isn't a subset and the fact still holds.

Comment: Thanks, that was dumb from me, I should know basic set theory ^^